# R error "no layer in plot"

Tags: r, rstudio

Code:

```
install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)

# load library
library(ggplot2)

api.hw.df.p <- ggplot(data = ecb.eurusd, aes(x = Date, y = Value))
api.hw.df.p
```

Error:

```
Error: No layers in plot
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify how to plot the data: points, line, bar, etc. Try something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = ecb.eurusd, aes(x = Date, y = Value)) + 
    geom_point()
```

This adds a *layer* containing points representing your data, which was lacking before, hence the error.